# Resource Management in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, resources, xcode4, universal

I'm wondering is there any way in XCode to control the resources that are included in the project, or more importantly included in the build itself.

What I'm trying to achieve is having a HD version of my app and a standard iPhone version. I would like to just have one project instead of two tho. I want to keep the app under 20mb so having all resources, HD and standard, included in both builds isn't a viable option. I'm assuming it is possible to do this through clever use of plists but I don't know nearly enough about the development environment to know what to start playing around with.

On a similar note is it possible to have a project to have different build settings, one to tell the compiler to build for ipad only and another to build for iphone only. Or is this just a project wide setting? If this is the case then what I'm trying to do may not even be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two targets in the project, one for iPhone, on e for iPad.  Then each can specify their resources and build options sharing code as applicable.

Comment: +1 - adding: this is easy to do by right-clicking the target (found by navigating to the project itself in the Project Navigator), then choosing to Duplicate the target.